# Performance issue when using bind variable for a large list inside the IN clause

Tags: sql, sybase, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using Sybase and had some code that looked like this:

```
String[] ids = ... an array containing 80-90k strings, which is retrieved from another table and varies.
for (String id : ids) {
    // wrap every id with single-quotes 
}
String idsAsString = String.join(",", ids); 
String query = String.format("select * from someTable where idName in (%s)", idsAsString);
getNamedParameterJDBCTemplate().query(query, resultSetExtractor ->{
    // do stuff with results
});
```

I've timed how long it took to get to the inner body of the resultSetExtractor and it never took longer than 4 seconds.

But to secure the code, I tried going the bind variable route. Thus, that code looked like the following:

```
String[] ids = ... an array containing 80-90k strings, which is retrieved from another table and varies.
String query = "select * from someTable where idName in (:ids)";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("ids", Arrays.asList(ids));
getNamedParameterJDBCTemplate().query(query, params, resultSetExtractor ->{
    // do stuff with results 
});
```

But doing it this way will take up to 4-5 minutes to finally spew out the following exception:

```
21-10-2019 14:04:01 DEBUG DefaultConnectionTester:126 - Testing a Connection in response to an Exception:
com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: The token datastream length was not correct. This is an internal protocol error.
```

I also have other bits of code where I pass in arrays of sizes 1-10 as bind variables and noticed that those queries went from being instantaneous to taking up to 10 seconds.

I'm surprised doing it the bind variable way is at all different, let alone *that* drastically different. Can someone explain what is going on here? Is it that bind variable does something different underneath the hood as opposed to sending a formatted string through JDBC? Is there another way to secure my code without drastically slowing performance?

Answer (score 0):

You should verify what's actually happening at the database end via a showplan/query plan, but using an 'in' clause will at best usually do one index search for every value in the 'in' clause, therefore 10 values does ten searches, 80k searches does 80k of them and thus massively slower. Oracle actually prohibits putting more than 1000 values in an 'in clause and whilst Sybase is not so restrictive that doesn't mean its a good idea. You risk stack and other issues in your database by putting massive amounts of values in this way I've seen such a query take out a production database instance with a stack failure.

It's much better to create a temporary table, load the 80k values into there and do an inner join between the temporary table and the main table using the column which previously you searched with the in clause.